# Fixed full width nav bar on loading

Tags: javascript, scroll

Please bear in mind that I'm not a coder.  I am using an existing website template.  I want to change the code to bring up my header, logo and menu on loading instead of on scroll.  The template can be found at:

http://seriftemplates.com/excell/

It has the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 940 && !$('#header, #logo, #menu').hasClass('open') ) {
    $('#header, #logo, #menu').addClass('open');
    $('#header, #logo, #menu').slideDown();
   } else if ( $(this).scrollTop() <= 940 ) {
    $('#header, #logo, #menu').removeClass('open');
    $('#header, #logo, #menu').slideUp();
  }
});
</script>
```

I changed the script to say slideDown instead of slideUp in the final line:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 940 && !$('#header, #logo, #menu').hasClass('open') ) {
    $('#header, #logo, #menu').addClass('open');
    $('#header, #logo, #menu').slideDown();
   } else if ( $(this).scrollTop() <= 940 ) {
    $('#header, #logo, #menu').removeClass('open');
    $('#header, #logo, #menu').slideUp();
  }
});
</script>
```

This made the bar appear immediately instead of after scrolling some distance down the page.  It also stopped it disappearing when I scrolled up again.

The page is here: https://www.valledesigns.com/scanning/index.html

However, what I really want is for my top header, logo, and menu to appear on loading and stay there when the page is scrolled.  Could this javascript function be changed to do this?

David

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.onload = ()=>{
    $('#header, #logo, #menu').addClass('open');
    $('#header, #logo, #menu').slideDown();
}
```

Just set the class to 'open' and slide down

repalce the script tag with

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = ()=>{
    $('#header, #logo, #menu').addClass('open');
    $('#header, #logo, #menu').slideDown();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help - really appreciate you taking the time to reply.  I knew it wouldn't be anything complicated, but after 8 hours of trying with no luck, I had to ask the experts!  I just replaced the script tag with your code and it worked.  Brilliant!